# Docker consuming more HD memory

Tags: docker, playframework, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have a play application and running in docker 1.10.3. We are hitting this applicaton with 1000 request per second to do a load test. Application works fine. We see a significant HD memory consumed by Docker. In 3 day the docker consumed fron 2.2gb to 39gb. This worries us a load.

Docker INFO and the consumed space highlighted
[image]

Is there any was to configre docker not to consumen HD memory?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which file(s) take all this space ? My guess would be a log file that keeps growing with the number of requests.

Comment: It is docker internal. It has nothing to do with the application. I just wanted to know if there is nay configuration in Docket to get rid of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker captures the standard output (STDOUT) of your application and stores it (by default) in an internal log file. You can find this file at `/var/lib/docker/containers/$CONTAINER_ID/$CONTAINER_ID-json.log`. This file is not rotated by default and may grow large if your application prints to STDOUT verbosely.

Two possible solutions:

1. Configure log rotation for the Docker log files. I've found a [good article here](https://sandro-keil.de/blog/2015/03/11/logrotate-for-docker-container/) that describes how to enable log rotation for Docker by creating the file `/etc/logrotate.d/docker-container` with the following contents:

   ```
   /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
     rotate 7
     daily
     compress
     size=1M
     missingok
     delaycompress
     copytruncate
   }
   ```

   You can play around with the options. They are all documented in [`logrotate`'s man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).
2. Use alternate logging for your containers by specifying the `--log-driver` option when creating a container:

   ```
   $ docker run --log-driver=syslog your_image
   ```

   Available drivers are documented in [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview). You can for example use `--log-driver=syslog` to use the system's syslog daemon, target various cloud services or disable logging entirely by using `--log-driver=none`.

Comment: Thank you will try out these options